# Why this simple query not using any one index?

Tags: mysql, sql, explain

Query:

```
SELECT *, history_count as `count` 
FROM pdf_history  
WHERE 1  AND history_date>=1426180929  AND history_count!=0
```

EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra 

1   SIMPLE  pdf_history ALL history_date,history_count  NULL    NULL    NULL    697 Using where
```

Comment: Do any indexes exist?

Comment: *Possible keys: history_date,history_count*

Comment: of couse, you can see it in explain "history_date,history_count"

Comment: how many rows are in your table?

Comment: What does `WHERE 1` do?

Comment: @juergend I thought that those were the rows with the filters

Comment: @Lamak: Hmm. Doc says: *Estimate of rows to be examined*

Comment: @juergend Ah, that just shows my ignorance about mySQL

Comment: @sstan It may be useful to comment multiple conditions http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97080/2/0 in dev mode.

Comment: @sstan its helper for sql builder

Comment: maybe the helper is not helping, and screwing up the db plan for exec

Comment: @juergend Anyway, if there are in fact 697 rows in that table, then what's the point of an index, really?, specially when using `SELECT *`

Comment: just show us the keys, composites and all. It can use a left-most then abandon from there with a where

Comment: @Drew  I exec it without WHERE 1, nothing changed

Comment: my point is that where 1 could theoretically be screwing it up. just show us the `show create table pdf_history`  or 17 people chasing their tails here

Comment: showing us what possible keys is/are is useless. we need the schema

Comment: `show create table pdf_history` http://paste.ofcode.org/pTPXXeGnBUrVErTAM4Tq3j

Comment: How could a single `1` cause so much comment frenzy :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason optimizer choose not to use the index is when the filter doesn't reduce the search space.

for example if

```
history_date>=1426180929
```

or

```
history_count!=0
```

already bring all the records then using the index doesnt really help.

My suggestion do this both querys and check the `ANALYZE`to see how many of the 
600 records are match that filter

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pdf_history WHERE history_date>=1426180929;
SELECT count(*) FROM pdf_history WHERE history_count!=0;
```

Comment: Now do the inverse query `history_date < 1426180929`  and `history_count = 0` those should use the index.

Comment: @NibikAlexander If the query returns the whole table, why would it use an index?

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza yes, its use index... thanks! Then I understant

Comment: I told you, why would optimizer use the index to scan 99% of the table, using index would be more expensive than a full scan